# Regex to check words in string are separated only by spaces and not by _AND_/_OR_ python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Regex in python to check if words in string are not separated by words like `_AND_,_OR_` and only separated by spaces.

meaning of underscore here is space after and before word AND/OR.

For eg:

1.) `foo AND bar` - should fail

2.) `foo AND bar cafe` - should fail because it has `_AND_`

3.) `foo AND bar OR cafe foobar baz` - fail because it has `_AND_/_OR_` in it

4.) `foo bar baz foobar` - pass because it is separated only spaces and no `_AND_/_OR_`

5.) `fooANDbarOR  bar` - pass because it is not separated by `_AND_/_OR_`.

I know how to check if words are separated by `_AND_/_OR_` ->

```
\W(:?AND|OR)\W
```

I know how to check if words are separated by spaces ->

```
\w\s
```

But i don't know how to combine both these things such that strings are separated only by spaces and not by `_AND_/_OR_`

Comment: Should `foo-AND-bar` fail? Should `AND` match?

Comment: Also, why don't you just use [`not bool([i for i in s.split() if i in ["AND", "OR"]])`](https://ideone.com/Xjdd2A)?

Comment: foo AND bar -> fail ; foo-AND-bar -> fail because foo-AND-bar will be taken as single word and there are no multiple words separated by spaces.

Comment: Please provide a sample string with expected output. I suspect you want to *extract substrings* rather than checking if a string contains `AND` or `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[\w ](?! (AND|OR) ))+$
```

The repeated `[\w ]` ensures that all characters are either word characters or spaces, nothing else. After each character, negative lookahead for `(AND|OR)` to ensure that neither of those are standalone words:

https://regex101.com/r/LyRr5U/2

If you also want to exclude standalone words, add positive lookahead to the beginning of the regex to ensure that there are some word characters separated by spaces somewhere in the string:

```
^(?=.*\w +\w)(?:[\w ](?! (AND|OR) ))+$
```

Comment: @certainperformace this regex also matches single words like : foo ; i only want to match words separated by spaces and they are not separated by AND/OR. So, single words should not match either.

Comment: Add some positive lookahead to the beginning of the regex. `^(?=.*\w\W+\w)` This ensures that there's at least one place where two word characters are separated by non-word characters.

Comment: There is still a mistake; this should match -> foo OR(because here it will be treated as two words separated by space, because there is no space after OR; so for eg: foo OR -> should not match because there is a space after and before OR

Comment: I think you should just replace \b in your answer with \W

Comment: Or, because we know that all characters are going to be word characters or spaces anyway, might as well be specific and use space characters rather than `\W` to avoid possible confusion

Comment: still we need an edit here,  ~secopssc  ~secops_if ; this should match but it doesnt ; its valid as string are separated by regex ; or we can say any word characters or non word characters separated by spaces should match

Comment: You should post all the requirements in your question *when you ask it* rather than asking a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). This is the first time you mentioned that non-word characters can be acceptable as well. Add `~` to the character set if you want that character to match as well: `^(?:[\w ~](?! (AND|OR) ))+$`

Comment: still this doesnt fit my need, i will post a question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048849/regex-to-match-words-non-words-regex-separated-by-only-spaces