# How to match character groups separated by spaces using RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I use the below RegEx to indentify if some string is separated by either `AND` or `OR`

```
\W(:?AND|OR)\
```

---

**Examples**

```
Input:  ~abc[0|1] AND foo
Output: Match
```

```
Input:  ~secopssc{1,3} AND ~abc_d{3,4}
Output: Match
```

---

Similarly, I want to write a regex which matches all the strings that are separated by only spaces and not by `AND` or `OR`.

I tried the below RegEx:

```
^(?=.*\w\W+\w)(?:[\w ](?!\W(AND|OR)\W))+$
```

---

**This gave the correct output on:**

```
Input:  foo bar
Output: Match
// This is correct since "foo" and "bar" are separated by a space
```

```
Input:  foo
Output: No Match
// This is correct since nothing is separated by a space
```

---

**But an incorrect output on:**

```
Input:  ~abc[0|1] foo
Output: No Match
// This is incorrect as both strings are separated by a space
```

```
Input:  ~secopssc{1,3} AND ~abc_d{3,4}
Output: No match
// This is incorrect as both strings are separated by a space
```

---

**To Summarise**: What is a way to check if a long string consists only of groups of characters separated just by spaces.

---

**Example of a valid string:**

```
foo{1,3} acb[1-2] a foo bar bar(qwer|qwyr)
```

(Valid since there are spaces separating each block of characters)

Comment: Do you want to check if a string contains a space?

Comment: just separated by spaces and not by words _AND_ / _OR_ (meaning of underscore is space) eg : foo AND bar is fine ; fooANDbar  will not match \W(:?AND|OR)\W

Comment: Does fooANDbar spam matches?

Comment: What, then, is your definition of a `word`? If you only want to check for spaces you can use `str.split()` and don't even need regex

Answer (score 0):

This solves my question:

```
k = "foo{1,3} acb[1-2] AND a foo bar bar(qwer|qwyr)"
if not re.search(r'\W(:?AND|OR)\W', k) and k.strip().find(" ")!=-1:
      print "not separated by AND and OR but by space"
else:
      print "separated by AND/OR"
```